# Highchart do-nut missing couple of slices

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have tried `Highchart` do-nut with `jQuery 1.8.3` and `1.10.1` and it seems to be still missing couple of pies. If I hover on the missing pies then it shows up. Any clue why such a behavior? Could it be because the number of pies are high?

[image: Missing pie slices]

[Link to the sample chart on Highchart website](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut)

**Adding jfiddle code shortly. Have to sanitize the code.**

Comment: How about some code, a link, or a fiddle? (to your dysfunctioning code)

Comment: If the sample code does not help then I can add some on fiddel. Will add anyways. Give me time to add the code on fiddle.

Comment: Does the Highchart website sample do the same thing for you? (it works fine for me)

Comment: It works fine is the number of pies are small. But when I start hitting a higher range I get this issue.

Comment: How can I reproduce ths issue and which browser do you use? Because I opened in Chrome, and problem seems to not appearing.